# How to scan, generate and print bar-code using C#.Net

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, barcode, barcode-scanner, barcode-printing

I want to create a C#.Net application, that does bar-code scanning, generating and printing.

How can I do that ?

Comment: What is the question ?

Answer (score 0):

A scanner in the domain is more often called a "wand". If the wand is USB simply plug it into a computer and open notepad and scan a bare code and the text will show.

If the want is Ethernet cable most likely you have a disk with driver for it and then you can do the same once these driver are installed on the computer.

A wand is just reading code, interpreting the real letters/numbers and repeating them as keyboard inputs. It can even read a "enter" key or "tab" key when transform to bare code

For bar code printing the thing is that bare code are actually fonts. you need to buy these fonts or you may have them with the driver disk of the wand. there are tons of different bare code and different wands can read multiple different bare code so you have to pay attention for that.

On the side oe, no one will produce code for you or give you final answer if you do not demonstrate that you at least tried some solution.